# Mudblazor - MudTable not able to align ToolbarContent

Tags: css, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I've been try to make some minor tweaks to the Toolbarcontent inside of a Mudtable without success. I recuced the size of the default MudTextField but I can't seem to find a way to align it to the right.

I also have a very light border around the toolbarcontent that I would like to remove but haven't found that setting either.

I found some posts that suggested using the "flex" box to do alignment but none of the examples I found dealt with it inside of the toolbarcontent. Any suggestions on what I need to do to get the TextField to be aligned to the right and/or how I can get rid of the outline around the toolbar?

```
 <MudTable Items="@listApplications" Dense="true" Hover="true" Bordered="true" Striped="true" CustomHeader="true" HeaderClass="mud-table-header"
            Filter="new Func<UsersAdminApp,bool>(FilterFunc1)" @bind-SelectedItem="selectedApplication">
        <ToolBarContent>
            <MudSpacer />
            <MudSpacer />
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString" Placeholder="Search for Application" Immediate="true" DebounceInterval="2" Clearable="true" Style="width: 300px;"
                Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense"
                Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0 flex-right"></MudTextField>
        </ToolBarContent>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `width` style has styled the border however, the container is still it's original width. See image below for what the width of the input container actually is.
[image: flexbox]

Since the parent of that input is also a flexbox that means that you can align the input using the `align-self` CSS property. Specifically for your use-case `align-self: end;`

```
<ToolBarContent>
    <MudTextField  @bind-Value="searchString" 
        Style="width: 300px;align-self:end;"
        Placeholder="Search for Application" Immediate="true" DebounceInterval="2" Clearable="true" 
        Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense"
        Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium"  Class="mt-0 flex-right"></MudTextField>
</ToolBarContent>
```

Another small tip is that you only need to use a `MudSpacer` if there are other components that you wish to place opposite to eachother.

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEwHOixlhRVOWIHy)

Comment: Perfect. Any tip on how to get rid of the light border that looks like it's going around the ToolBarContent area?

Comment: That would be by setting `Elevation="0"` on the table however that will remove all the borders for the table.